# How to write a binary filefrom a netcdf file?

Tags: r, binary

I would like to write a binary file from a netcdf file

```
library(ncdf)
download.file("http://gswp/Fixed/SoilDepth.nc", destfile="SoilDepth.nc")
soil <- open.ncdf("SoilDepth.nc")
soil$var[[3]] -> var3 
get.var.ncdf(soil, var3) -> SoilDepth
download.file("http://gswp/Fixed/landmask_gswp.nc", destfile="landmask.nc")
landmask <- open.ncdf("landmask.nc")
landmask$var[[3]] -> varland
get.var.ncdf(landmask, varland) -> land
land = t(land)
land[land==1] <- SoilDepth
land[land==0] <- NA
land = t(land)
image(land)
```

the result of This code will look like:![map of soil][1]

Now I want to write it to a binary file:

The result is an image upside down.

Comment: where is the write? Also what is with all the transposing? You would benefit from working carefully at each step to get rid of unneeded code. Just use [ to reorder by rows/columns

Comment: What mdsumner probably meant was something like `y <- y[nrow(y):1,]` to reverse the rows of matrix `y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You requested a reverse orientation yourself, by specifying `ylim=c(1,0)`. Simply change that last line to

```
image(y)
```

and you'll be fine, as the double transpose does nothing except eat resources.

*Further information:* The only difference between the original and the re-read data is the fact that the latter has `NaN` (i.e. Not a Number) in the places where the former had `NA` (Not Available). Undoing this modification yields completely identical data:

```
y[is.nan(y)] <- NA
```

After this, `y` becomes indistinguishable from `land`.